# hover close button over image generated by jQuery ajax call

Tags: jquery, css

I have an image picker which uses jQuery and ajax to show images in a modal and after selecting the desired images and clicking, "save", the selected images are displayed.

html:

```
<div class="thumbs"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$( ".save" ).on("click", function() {
        $( ".thumbs" ).empty();
        $( 'input[name="pics[]"]:checked' ).each(function() {
        $( ".thumbs" ).append("<img src='uploads/" +$(this).val()+"'>");
    });
});
```

css:

```
.thumbs img {

float: left;
width: 90px;
height: 90px;
margin-right: 1%;
margin-bottom: 0.5em;
margin-top: 0.5em;
background-size: cover;
border-radius: 5em;
position: relative;
}
```

This is the close button I want to sit on the top right hand of the image.

```
.thumbs-close {

    width: 23px;
    height: 23px;
    top: -5px;
    right: -5px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

I tried placing that class in the div as well as the img tag but neither way end up displaying the x in the red circle as I want:

```
<div class="thumbs"><div class="thumbs-close">x</div></div>
```

Comment: Is issue that `,thumbs-close` is not displaying at all, or is it just a matter of it not displaying in the way you need it to? `$( ".thumbs" ).empty();` will also remove the `.thumbs-close` element as well.

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError, it is displaying but not at all how I want. Deepening on what I change "position" style to it either shows at the top right hand corner of the form(wrong) or shows them all in a row next to the last image(also, wrong). I want them to show on the top right corner of each image.

Comment: Have you tried adding `.position: relative;` to the containing parent element `.thumbs`?

Comment: Do you mean like? `.thumbs { position:relative; }`

Comment: Yes, that's it - I realise my typo could've thrown you off there.

Comment: This is what google chrome is showing when I have selected 2 images: `<div class="thumbs"><div class="thumbs-close">x</div><img src="uploads/meadow-2184989_640.jpg"><img src="uploads/wave-2211925_640.jpg"></div>`

Comment: Rather wrap each `img` tag in a containing element, which you can `position: relative` so that the `right` and `top` values you have declared for your `absolute` elements will be relative to the position of each `img` element, e.g: `<div class="thumbs"><div class="thumb-wrapper" style="position: relative;"><img src="uploads/hand-2223109_640.jpg"><div class="thumbs-close">x</div></div></div>`

Comment: Is the intention to have more than one `.thumbs-close`? I get that impression from the way you phrased here "I want them to show on the top right corner of each image", but in the example you've included above I only see one.

Comment: yes, that's my problem with that. I am only seeing one and it's in completely the wrong positiong

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156775/discussion-between-user8463989-and-uncaughttypeerror).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following semantic structure...

`$( ".thumbs" ).append("<div class="thumb-wrapper"><img src='uploads/" +$(this).val()+"'><div class='thumbs-close'>x</div></div>");`

Style `.thumb-wrapper` with `position: relative`

```
.thumb-wrapper {
position: relative;
}
```

Each close button should now be `top: -5px` and `right: -5px` from the containing parent element `.thumb-wrapper`; which has been positioned relative.